# python random.shuffle() in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
    k = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Now I want 3 permutations of this list to be listed in another list but when I do this:

```
    x = []
    i = 0
    while i < 3:
        random.shuffle(k)
        x.append(k)
        i += 1
```

I end up with 3 times the same permutation of k in x, like this:

```
    x = [[1,3,5,2,4], [1,3,5,2,4], [1,3,5,2,4]]
```

In stead of what I would like, something like this:

```
    x = [[1,5,4,2,3], [1,3,5,2,4], [5,3,4,1,2]]
```

Note that it is not possible due to the way the data in k is gathered to place k inside the loop, as for I know this would solve the problem. The real code is this:

```
    def create_random_chromosomes(genes):
        temp_chromosomes = []
        chromosomes = []
        i = 0
        while i < 2000:
            print(genes)
            random.shuffle(genes)
            temp_chromosomes.append(genes)
            i += 1
        print(temp_chromosomes)
        for element in temp_chromosomes:
            if element not in chromosomes:
                chromosomes.append(element)
        return chromosomes
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shuffling a list changes it in-place, and you are creating 3 references to the same list. Create a *copy* of the list before shuffling:

```
x = []
for i in range(3):
    kcopy = k[:]
    random.shuffle(kcopy)
    x.append(kcopy)
```

I've simplified your loop as well; just use `for i in range(3)`. Or, to place this in the context of your full method:

```
def create_random_chromosomes(genes):
    temp_chromosomes = []
    chromosomes = []
    for i in range(2000):
        print(genes)
        randomgenes = genes[:]
        random.shuffle(randomgenes)
        temp_chromosomes.append(randomgenes)
    print(temp_chromosomes)
    for element in temp_chromosomes:
        if element not in chromosomes:
            chromosomes.append(element)
    return chromosomes
```

You can further simplify the above by using a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to weed out dupes:

```
def create_random_chromosomes(genes):
    chromosomes = set()
    randomgenes = genes[:]
    for i in range(2000):
        random.shuffle(randomgenes)
        chromosomes.add(tuple(randomgenes))
    return list(chromosomes)
```

This uses a tuple copy of the random genes list to fit the [hashable](http://docs.python.org/py3k/glossary.html#term-hashable) constraint of set contents.

You can then even ensure that you return 2000 unique items regardless:

```
def create_random_chromosomes(genes):
    chromosomes = set()
    randomgenes = genes[:]
    while len(chromosomes) < 2000:
        random.shuffle(randomgenes)
        chromosomes.add(tuple(randomgenes))
    return list(chromosomes)
```

Comment: Thankyou, that works fine, I had already tried doing the same thing but didn't add the '[:]' to the k when making the copy and it didn't work, so what does adding '[:]' do exactly?

Comment: `[:]` means: give me all elements in the list (from the start to the end) as a new list. Compare this to `[:10]` or `[10:]`; omitting the start or end numbers sets them to the default of 0 and len(list).

Comment: you can also use `list(k)` instead of `k[:]`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: most python devs use `[:]` as it is half the characters of `list(..)`.

Comment: Seems like it would be more efficient to make a single copy of the list outside the loop and then just keep (re)shuffling that...

Comment: @martineau: you'd have to make copies of the shuffled list still, otherwise you still are appending only a reference to it to the result.

Comment: @martineau: creating a single copy outside the list is, in other words, still the exact same problem; you are modifying one list, in place, and only adding references.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Oh..yeah, it would, sorry. In that case how about just the single line `x.append(random.sample(k, len(k)))` in the loop?

Comment: @martineau: sure, that's also an option.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: In a similar vain for your updated answer using sets, since you're adding a tuple constructed each time from the list rather than a reference, it seems like making a copy to shuffle each time is unnecessary.

Comment: @martineau: Ah, true, the tuple() call makes moving the randomgenes copy out of the loop a good idea.

Comment: Using sets to guarantee generation of unique combinations seems both useful and very clever. +1